# How do I integrate a Flutter application with ipynb/colab notebook?

Tags: python, flutter, rest, tensorflow, hosting

We currently have a working application that is ready to post and get data from an API which displays results of predicted disease (purpose of the ML model). Right now we don't have an exact idea on how to make the .ipynb communicate with the application provided we have large data for training the model.

We have 2 .ipynb files `Model.py` and `Predict.py`. One performing the required pre-processing, split (for train, test and validation), train and save the model. Predict uses the saved model and classifies the user input.

The main concern is how do we send the data from User's end-point(Flutter Application) to `Predict.py` and get the result data back to the user on the application.

We have considered the idea of hosting the model with prediction somewhere, but do not know on how to proceed further.

**This is my first encounter with handling Deep Learning with Flutter Application. Any kind of information on proceeding forward will be very helpful.**

Answer (score 0):

First, .ipynb files are Jupyter Notebooks.

Second, do you have your API ready ? Is there a server dedicated to it or is there only the flutter app, that is ony the front of your application.

If you do not have an API, you have to create one (using whatever framework you want).
To facilitate things, create it in Python, and you can directly import your model as a Python module and use it.

Comment: Basically, we have only the front end and the model which is predicting the data according to our requirement i.e., label and data. We are not knowing on how to proceed further with the API. Could you please suggest us some frameworks and hosting that you mentioned in the answer please. Thank you.

Comment: You can use fastAPI for example, it's really quick to do it with it.

Comment: have you solve this? I just found that there is a TensorFlow Lite plugin for Flutter. I don't know if it works with .ipynb files since in the documentation says that it need a .tflite model file, but maybe could be an interesting point to start.